# SQL statement returns only one record

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

In Orders Table i have the following data:

```
OrderNum | Item | Quantity|
1234     | EE1  | 1       |
1234     | EE3  | 1       |
1235     | EE2  | 1       |
1236     | EE5  | 1       |
1236     | EE8  | 1       |
```

I want to display in datagridview those order with an order number of 1234.

This is my codes..but it only display one record..the EE1 item only.

```
        con.Open();
        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo="+Convert.ToInt32(txtStudNo.Text)+"";

        reader = com.ExecuteReader();


        int indx = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[indx];

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                com2.CommandText = "SELECT Description, Price FROM Books WHERE BookID='" + reader[2].ToString() + "'";
                reader2 = com2.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader2.Read())
                    {
                        row.Cells[0].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                        row.Cells[1].Value = reader2[0].ToString();
                        row.Cells[2].Value = reader[4].ToString();
                        row.Cells[3].Value = reader2[1].ToString();
                    }

                }
```

need some help.. please.

Comment: If you debug this, you would probably find that the result set is returning more than one row of data. The problem is that you are simply overwriting the same row in your grid with the data.

Comment: You only ADD one row. It is the same row you keep assigning different values to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing all records to just one row:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[indx];
```

To not overwriting the datanalready written to the gridview, you have to increase the `indx` value and get another row reference for each record.

Maybe the following code is working for you?

```
con.Open();
com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo="+Convert.ToInt32(txtStudNo.Text)+"";

reader = com.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int indx = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[indx];

        com2.CommandText = "SELECT Description, Price FROM Books WHERE BookID='" + reader[2].ToString() + "'";
        reader2 = com2.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader2.Read())
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = reader[2].ToString();
            row.Cells[1].Value = reader2[0].ToString();
            row.Cells[2].Value = reader[4].ToString();
            row.Cells[3].Value = reader2[1].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I do that..I try a lot of ideas, but my ideas are wrong.